# Intersection Observer для первого элемента во viewport'е

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть вот такой [референс](https://dribbble.com/shots/3912071-Lenmix):

[image]

Суть эффекта - на странице показаны года и какой-то контент (текст) к ним. При скролле страницы, выбирается самый первый из них, находящийся в области видимости, и к нему добавляется класс, на котором завязаны стили для его выделения.

Хочу реализовать его с помощью [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

В голову приходит только добавление класса заголовкам, находящимся в поле видимости (in-viewport), с помощью [IO](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), а затем через каждые 50-100мс обновлять список всех активных заголовков и только первому в списке добавлять еще один класс (active), на котором уже завязаны стили для самого эффекта.

Возможны ли еще какие-то решения? Нужна помощь не столько в коде, сколько в правильном выборе подхода решения задачи.

Comment: Куда ведёт первая ссылка и зачем?

Comment: это ссылка на эффект, которого я хочу добиться

Comment: Не понимаю, о каком эффекте речь. К тому же, описание должно быть в вопросе.

Comment: постарался описать проблему подробней.

Comment: Я бы обрабатывал непосредственно скролл и ничего не химичил.